# Access scrollPhase in NSEvent

Tags: cocoa

How do I access the property `scrollPhase` in an `NSEvent` of type `NSScrollEvent` (in OS X 10.6)?

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Scroll Event: %@", event);
}
```

If I write the event to the log, I can see the desired information:

```
... Scroll Wheel Event: NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel ... scrollPhase=Continue
... Scroll Wheel Event: NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel ... scrollPhase=End
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in [the public API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-SW31). Of course you can access it by calling a Apple private method. If you use private APIs, you should know what you're doing, so I won't spell out how to do that here, other than pointing out how to get the method name: just use the utility [`class-dump`](http://www.google.com/search?q=class-dump).

Answer (score 0):

As of OSX 10.7, the `phase` is now available in the [public API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/phase).